# TypeError: not a function

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-promise

I am getting a type error invoking below userRequest function -

> angular.min.js:107 TypeError: $scope.userRequest.then is not a function

```
$scope.userRequest = function() {
    if ($scope.realm === 'example') {
        return service.getUserDetails($scope.username)
            .then(function(data) {
                ...
                return data;
            });
    } else {
        return $q.reject($scope.realm + ' not supported');
    }
};
```

```
$scope.userRequest.then(function(user) {
    return service.getUserRides(user.email);
}).then(function(data) {
   ...
}).catch(function(error) {
   ...
})
```

Please let me know how I can fix the error?

Comment: `userRequest` is a function, not a promise. You can use it like `$scope.userRequest().then(...)` but I think it will cause another issue since the function does not return a promise. I suggest you to restructure your `userRequest` function.

Comment: Remove `.then(function(data) {
                ...
                return data;
            });` from $scope.userRequest function . then use the promise chaining .Just return  return service.getUserDetails($scope.username)

Comment: @HarunYilmaz The `$scope.userRequest()` returns a promise because both `service.getUserDetails()` and `$q.reject()` return promises.

Comment: @georgeawg Yeah you are right. I missed that part. However the first part is accurate I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invoke the function to get the promise:

```
̶$̶s̶c̶o̶p̶e̶.̶u̶s̶e̶r̶R̶e̶q̶u̶e̶s̶t̶.̶t̶h̶e̶n̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶(̶u̶s̶e̶r̶)̶ ̶{̶
$scope.userRequest().then(function(user) {
    return service.getUserRides(user.email);
}).then(function(data) {
   //...
}).catch(function(error) {
   //...
})
```